# Entropy Loss in Linear Filters

Tags: dft, linear-systems, information-theory

I've been trying to figure out the result for the entropy loss/entropy gain in linear systems derived in "The Mathematical Theory of Communication" by Claude Shannon.

Claude Shannon states that

> If an ensemble having an entropy $H_{1}$ per degree of freedom in band $W$ is passed through a filter with characteristic $Y(f)$ the output ensemble has an entropy
> $$H_{2} = H_{1}+\frac{1}{W}\int\limits_{W}\log |Y(f)|^2 df$$

I don't undestand why Shannon uses the fact that the Jacobian of a linear transformation is $J=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}|Y(f_{i})|^2$ ($n$ is the number of the Fourier transform components)

I can show that the Jacobian of a linear transformation $J=|\det A|$ where $A$ is the matrix that characterizes the transformation. I can also show that for the case of linear *time-invariant* systems $A$ can be diagonalized by the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) matrix and then since the DFT matrix is unitary, I get $J=|\det A|=|\det \{F^{-1}\Lambda F\}|=|\det\Lambda|=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}|Y(f_{i})|$ as $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix, that is the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of its diagonal elements and I set $\lambda_{ii}=Y(f_{i})$.

This result differs from the mentioned above ($J=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}|Y(f_{i})|^2$), though I cannot find a flaw in my logic. What am I doing wrong?

Also, is it correct that actually $H_{2} = H_{1}+\frac{1}{W}\int\limits_{W}\log |Y(f)|^2 df$ implies the integral to be $\frac{1}{W}\int\limits_{0}^{W}\log |Y(f)|^2 df$ and not $\frac{1}{W}\int\limits_{-W}^{W}\log |Y(f)|^2 df$?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps this is off base (I have the book but haven't read it) but any signal/process has to be Y-> Y x (Y*) in going from linear to power  domain; Y* is the complex argument.  And I think that is where Entropy is predicated to measured.  It certainly is for noise calculations.  I've done quite a few of those calculations, and they work out.

Comment: @rrogers Shannon claims that the Jacobian is squared due to the fact there are n sine and n cosine components, I guess his result is somehow related to this. When I start with the DFT, I get n/2-1 distinct components for a real signal since the DC and the n/2 component aren't paired. Whatever, I would like to also check your version. Could you check some sources or examples please?

Comment: @GuntherOnFire Do not exclude the possibility that Shannon was wrong. Indeed, there is a paper that claims the Shannon's theorem does not hold in the general cases (see [this](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/23/8/947/pdf)). The authors do include a formal proof for the theorem (I did not read it carefully but it seems ok). Check the paper and tell us if you find the answer to your question.

Comment: @GuntherOnFire Rather than get mired down in (esoteric?) details of signals and such; how about an illustration using fair (random) dice versus unfair (determined) dice versus cheating (which will be a little complicated and probably unnecessarily complicated :) ); and applying the law of large numbers?  Actual calculation versus the writeup on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law   
which is itself a little technical :)  The extension to sampled data, z xform, is reasonably obvious; as is tacit  assumptions.

Comment: The extension to "linear xforms" does require some thought; but the whole of signal analysis requires some intuition for guidance.  Basically, there are some "symmetries" /conditions that get drug in.  The whole area of "randomness" is subject to mathematical discussion.